# SharePoint current/quick navigation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I'm facing a strange problem with one of our SharePoint administrators. He can only see a few heading/links under current/quick navigation. Up until yesterday he could see the full list.

I have checked under site settings and navigation where the full list is displayed. Please note he has all the required permissions and its only happening with him. Everyone else can see the full list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say Administrator, do you mean farm admin and/or site collection admin?

Comment: Thanks AdamBt. I would say farm admin. as he is part of SharePoint administrator team

Comment: I would try explicitly making him a site owner or site collection administrator and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response. i believe he is site owner. in fact he is the one who created this teamsite in question. as I said earlier full list was visible but all of sudden about half of the list has stopped appearing.

Comment: try to remove his permission from site collection and re add him? or also remove from User Information table. check if that fix the issue. removing and re adding is easy becuase he is site collection admin.